# Match multiple tables optimization Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have 3 nodes with labels in Neo4j database - Applications, Phone Contacts Book, Sms.
I am trying to write the query which by similar contacts and the names in sms would retrieve all the applications id.
However, the query I wrote executes for a while and crashes with an error about heap decrease.
How can I optimize my query?

```
MATCH (pcb:PhoneContactsBook {phone: pcb.phone})-[:APP_PCB]->
      (a:Applications)-[:APP_SMS]->
      (sms:Sms {address: sms.address}) 
RETURN distinct pcb.phone, 
       collect(a.application_id);
```

I tried to set indexes on the fields used for filtering (like sms.address), but it runs even longer with them.

Here is the query plan:
[image]

Comment: Why do you compare the values of a property with the same property - `{phone: pcb.phone}` and `{address: sms.address}`?

Comment: Because I want to find out how many applications were created with the same phone numbers and contacts names in sms

Answer (score 2):

As @stdob points out, the 2 following node patterns in your `MATCH` clause do not make any sense (and are likely the cause of your crash):

```
(pcb:PhoneContactsBook {phone: pcb.phone})

(sms:Sms {address: sms.address})
```

The first node pattern is looking for a `PhoneContactsBook` node whose `phone` value equals itself, and the second node pattern is looking for an `Sms` node whose `address` value equals itself. Since these patterns will match all `PhoneContactsBook` and `Sms` nodes (as long as they have `phone` and `address` properties, respectively), your `MATCH` clause ends up doing a more expensive version of the following snippet, which does no filtering by phone number or address at all:

```
MATCH (pcb:PhoneContactsBook)-[:APP_PCB]->(a:Applications)-[:APP_SMS]->(sms:Sms)
```

Your query is thus probably causing a very large number of matches, which takes a long time and eventually causes the DB to run out of heap.

You have not provided enough information on your data model for me to know how you can fix this. However, if I correctly assume that a `PhoneContactsBook` node contains an `address` property, and an `Sms` node contains a `phone` property, perhaps you meant the following?

```
MATCH (pcb:PhoneContactsBook {phone: sms.phone})-[:APP_PCB]->
      (a:Applications)-[:APP_SMS]->
      (sms:Sms {address: pcb.address}) 
RETURN distinct pcb.phone, 
       collect(a.application_id);
```

*By the way, you should use the correct terminology. Since neo4j is a graph DB, it has no "tables". Instead, `Applications`, `PhoneContactsBook`, and `Sms` are node "labels".*

Comment: Yes, I have pcb.displayname field which matches sms.address field, however, the number of matches is quite small in comparison with the dataset. And, unfortunately, I do not have sms.phone field